# How can I configure BlueJeans web app so that the microphone is muted by default when joining a meeting?

Tags: privacy, bluejeans

How can I configure BlueJeans web app so that the microphone is muted by default when joining a meeting?

On the BlueJeans desktop program one can configure BlueJeans so that the microphone is muted by default when joining a meeting:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the BlueJeans tech support, one cannot configure BlueJeans web app so that the microphone is muted by default when joining a meeting.